# How to restrict user access to a particular Git repository in VSTS?

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have created few Git repositories in VSTS. Now we have team members who work on various projects and technologies. For example in our case we have iOS, Android and Angular code bases mapped to dedicated Git repos in VSTS. I want to restrict the access of iOS team member from access/ or doing any kind of operations against other Git repos setup in VSTS.

Can anyone help me to provide their guidance here to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the repo security settings (Click the gear icon, go to 'Version Control', then choose your repo).

You'll see that there are existing groups that have access to the repos (Contributors, Administrators, etc).

If everyone is a member of Contributors, everyone has access to the repos. You may want to break your Contributors down a bit, into different "types" of contributor -- "iOS Contributor", "Android Contributor", etc. Then you just need to make sure the appropriate security group is applied to the appropriate repo.

You'll want to use "Deny" permissions sparingly -- an explicit Deny overrides an explicit Allow. You can read them like this:

- "Allow": Allow access unless denied
- "Deny": Do not allow access under any circumstances
- "Not Set": Deny access unless allowed

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It helped me to fix the access issue :)